# When put my Task inside loop it work only once

Tags: c#, winforms

In my application i am taking file after from my `Listbox` and run this files using my class, also i have loop option if i want to continue play all my files from my list box after the application finish all the files i.e start again all the files so i put my Task that exist in my Play button click inside While but the it run my files only in the first time and after in doesn't not continue even if my `numericUpDownLoops.Value == 2` and `loopCount = 1`

```
NumericUpDown numericUpDownLoops;

        private void btnPlay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int loopCount = 0;

            if (loopCount < numericUpDownLoops.Value)
            {
                Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                    var files = listBoxFiles.Items.Cast<string>().ToList();
                    Parallel.ForEach(files,
                                     new ParallelOptions
                                     {
                                         MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 1 // limit number of parallel threads 
                                     },
                                     file =>
                                     {
                                         //play my file
                                     });
                }).ContinueWith(
 t =>
 {         
     loopCount++;
 }
, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext() // to ContinueWith (update UI) from UI thread
);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Why do you call `Parallel.ForEach` then set the `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` to 1, you are removing the "parallelness" of the function. A normal `foreach` would be much less overhead.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a loop on numericUpDownLoops.Value - you check a condition, and start a single task that processes files in parallel. Try changing the `if()` to a `while()`.